# fineuploader setname with options

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying to renname a file using fine uploader and the change keeps getting ignored

$(this).fineUploader({setName: {id: new_name}});

new_name of course was set earlier.

This seems to be correct and doesn't throw an error but just doesn't work. 
Any ideas

Comment: Please don't use the jQuery wrapper - it provides no real benefits and will be removed in the next major release. Instead, just call the `setName` method directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `setName` function can be called from jQuery using the below syntax.  Note that we are plugging into the `onSubmit` event in order to obtain an `id` of a file which `setName` requires.

```
var $uploader =
    $(this).fineUploader({
    })
    .on("submit", function (event, fileId, fileName) {
        $uploader.fineUploader("setName", fileId, new_name);
    });
```